# When reading from a file new lines break my enqueue and push methods

Tags: c

```
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
        char input[80];
        if (fp == NULL) { 
            perror("Error");
            exit(1);
            fclose(fp);
        }

        Node* stack = NULL;
        Node* queue = NULL;

        while (fgets(input, 80, fp)) {
            const char *space = " \f\n\r\t\v";
            char* tokenS = strtok(input, space);

            while (tokenS != NULL) {
                printf("test %s\n", tokenS);
                queue = enqueue(queue, tokenS);
                stack = push(stack, tokenS);
                tokenS = strtok(NULL, space);
            }
        }
        printf("--Queue--\n");
        printList(queue);
        printf("--Stack--\n");
        printList(stack);
```

When reading a file with words separated by a space. This works when the file only has one line. Once I have multiple lines I start getting unexpected output.
For example, for input

```
hello world man bye boy
a
```

I get the output.

```
test hello
test world
test man
test bye
test boy
test a
--Queue--
a
world
man
bye
boy
a
--Stack--
a
boy
bye
man
world
a
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with my loops? I'm not quite sure.

EDIT:
SOLVED by strdup the value of tokenS. Thanks!

```
while (tokenS != NULL) {
                char* data = strdup(tokenS);
                printf("%s\n",data);
                queue = enqueue(queue, data);
                stack = push(stack, data);
                tokenS = strtok(NULL, space);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you making a copy of the data when you save it to the stack or queue?  If not, you're probably just saving a pointer to data that is overwritten by the next line of input, changing the data on the stack or queue (or both).  If you use a longer second line (`the answer is data overwriting`, for example, instead of just `a`), you should see more clearly what's going wrong.

Comment: `char* tokenS = strtok(input, space);` receives a pointer pointing to an address within `input`. With every call to `fgets` you will change what is at the addresses previously assigned. You need to create a copy of `tokenS` and store that. (as written, all pointers in your `stack` and `queue` will end up pointing to whatever was in the last `input` read)

Comment: Can we see your `enqueue` and `push` functions? Do they allocate memory and copy the data into the newly-allocated memory? If not, where are you expecting the data to be stored?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
You are both correct, I have added a temp char pointer inside the loop and strdup(tokens) to that. Then enqueue/pushed that temp char pointer. That seems to have fixed the issue.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Beware memory leaks — you now need to free the duplicated data at some point, which involves changes to your program too.  But the problem you faced was recognizable; it's a common problem.  Also, you need to think carefully about whether it is OK for the stack and the queue to share the same string.  How do you know when it is safe to release it?  You probably need one copy for the stack and one for the queue.

Comment: `fclose(NULL)` is pointless, almost certainly going to fail, and executed (or not!) after `exit`.  You can delete that line.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment above, when tokenizing `input` with `tokenS`, the address held by `tokenS` points to an address within `input`. When you call `fgets` again, all previous pointers end up pointing to the new information in `input` as you have overwritten what was in `input` by the next call to `fgets`.

To solve the problem, simply allocate storage for `tokenS` (say in `tokenScpy`) and then store the copy in `stack` and `queue`. Each `tokenScpy` will point to a separate block of memory with *allocated storage duration*, and will not affected by any changes you make to `input`. (you are also responsible for freeing each block with the memory is no longer needed)

If you have POSIX `strdup` available, that can provide the allocation and copy in a single-call. (**but note:** `strdup()` allocates, so you should check that the allocatin succeeds, just as if you had called `malloc()` yourself.

With `strdup()` you could do:

```
#define DELIM " \f\n\r\t\v"

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
        char input[80];
        if (fp == NULL) { 
            perror("Error");
            exit(1);
            fclose(fp);
        }

        Node* stack = NULL;
        Node* queue = NULL;

        while (fgets(input, 80, fp)) {
            const char *space = DELIM;

            while (tokenS != NULL) {
                char *tokenScpy = strdup (tokenS);
                if (!tokenScpy) {   /* strdup allocate, you validate */
                    perror ("malloc-tokenScpy");
                    break;
                }
                printf("test %s\n", tokenScpy);
                queue = enqueue(queue, tokenScpy);
                stack = push(stack, tokenScpy);
                tokenS = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
            }
        }
        printf("--Queue--\n");
        printList(queue);
        printf("--Stack--\n");
        printList(stack);
```

(**note:** `#define DELIM " \f\n\r\t\v"` was used instead of `const char *space = " \f\n\r\t\v";` simply due to `space` never changing, either way is fine)

If `strdup()` is not available, then a simple call to `malloc` and `memcpy` will accomplish the same thing, e.g.

```
            while (tokenS != NULL) {
                size_t len = strlen (tokenS);
                char *tokenScpy = malloc (len + 1);
                if (!tokenScpy) {   /* validate every allocation */
                    perror ("malloc-tokenScpy");
                    break;
                }
                memcpy (tokenScpy, tokenS, len + 1);
                printf("test %s\n", tokenScpy);
                queue = enqueue(queue, tokenScpy);
                stack = push(stack, tokenScpy);
                tokenS = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
            }
```

**Note:** as Mr. Leffler points out, both `queue` and `stack` will store the same copy of `tokenScpy` which is fine so long as there is only a single `free()` called on each pointer. If your *stack* and *queue* routines each have their own `free()` of the pointers stored -- you will need to make a second copy of each token so that each will have a copy of its own. In that case you could do something similar to:

```
        while (fgets(input, 80, fp)) {
            const char *space = DELIM;

            while (tokenS != NULL) {
                char *tokenScpys = strdup (tokenS),
                     *tokenScpyq = strdup (tokenS);
                /* strdup allocate, you validate */
                if (!tokenScpys || !tokenScpyq) {
                    perror ("malloc-tokenScpys/tokenScpyq");
                    break;
                }
                printf("tests %s  testq %s\n", tokenScpys, tokenScpyq);
                queue = enqueue(queue, tokenScpyq);
                stack = push(stack, tokenScpys);
                tokenS = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that a single copy of the token can be placed on both the stack and the queue if the memory is subsequently freed?  If the queue and stack are not handled in appropriate synchrony (which is unlikely, given FIFO vs LIFO operation), there'll be problems accessing freed data somewhere along the line (if the tokens are ever freed).  It would be safer to make two copies — one for the queue, one for the stack — so that the operation of the two are independent.  I'd probably put the duplication code in the `enqueue` and `push()` functions.

Comment: Oooh good point, if there will not be a coordinated common free, then a second copy to store in stack should be made. Not enough information to know.

Comment: From my Guidelines: Your program will have to read from a file or standard input, take all the words and put each word in a node in two linked lists. After reading the file and populating the lists you will have to print both the lists. The file should be standard text file with multiple lines and multiple words. Each
word is separated by a space.

At the end of the program you must properly delete both lists.

I'm assuming by properly delete both lists, I must free the memory of each? Can't I just have a function that does that?

Comment: @nebulaEXE yes you can. However, you must preserve a pointer to the beginning address of each block of memory allocated so it can be freed. In your case that would mean either preserving a linked list of all allocated blocks that you would call free on after your use of both *stack* and *queue* was complete (because removing values from the stack and queue would lose the pointer to each block unless it was preserved elsewhere). Or, just have your stack and queue free each pointer when it is removed -- but requiring you make a second copy.